# What is the right way to make a search bar in Flutter without unnecessary calls to Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add a search bar to my Flutter application. My goal is to use it to filter a list of items in a ListView. I am using Cloud Firestore for the database part and I want to use its ability to update the data list in real time via its snapshot system.

Here is what I have right now. I have tried to make it as simple as possible so sorry if the code is ugly :

```
  // This controller handles the search string.
  final TextEditingController _filter = new TextEditingController();

  ListView _listView;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // The widget is rebuilt every time the search string changes.
    // I tried to use _listView.build(context) instead but it does not work.
    _filter.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: _buildStream(_user),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {  

          // Filter the snapshot documents.
          var itemList = new List<MyItem>();
          var allDocuments = snapshot.data.documents;
          for (var i = 0; i < allDocuments.length; i++) {
            var documentSnapshot = allDocuments[i];
            MyItem item = MyItem.fromSnapshot(documentSnapshot);
            if (item.name.contains(_filter.text)) itemList.add(item);
          }

          _listView = ListView.builder(
            itemCount: itemList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, i) =>
                _buildListItem(context, itemList[i], i),
          );
          return _listView;
        });
  }

  Stream<QuerySnapshot> _buildStream(User user) {
    return Firestore.instance
        .collection('items')
        .where('testId', isEqualTo: user.ID)
        .snapshots();
  }
```

Basically, I make the filtering part in the StreamBuilder's builder.
This code gives me the result I want but I am concerned about the fact that it will call Firestore every time a letter is added or removed in the search bar. It is not optimal in terms of performance and also, in my understanding, I will be billed by Firestore everytime the user changes the search string even though the same items are returned over and over again. I know that usually Firestore snapshots are able to update in realtime and you get only charged for the differences with the previous snapshot but I do not think it works in that case because the whole widget is rebuilt everytime someone changes the search string.

Obviously, doing the filtering in _buildStream would be cleaner but I will still have the same issue regarding billing.
Doing it in the builder seems to be the only option.

I cannot find a way to prevent rebuilding the whole widget and avoid these unnecessary calls.
Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up building the stream during the initialization of the widget.

```
  // This controller handles the search string.
  final TextEditingController _filter = new TextEditingController();

  ListView _listView;
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> _stream; // <-------------------- ADDED THIS

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _stream = _buildStream(_user); // <-------------------- ADDED THIS

    // The widget is rebuilt every time the search string changes.
    // I tried to use _listView.build(context) instead but it does not work.
    _filter.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: _stream, // <-------------------- CHANGED THIS
        builder: (context, snapshot) {  

          // Filter the snapshot documents.
          var itemList = new List<MyItem>();
          var allDocuments = snapshot.data.documents;
          for (var i = 0; i < allDocuments.length; i++) {
            var documentSnapshot = allDocuments[i];
            MyItem item = MyItem.fromSnapshot(documentSnapshot);
            if (item.name.contains(_filter.text)) itemList.add(item);
          }

          _listView = ListView.builder(
            itemCount: itemList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, i) =>
                _buildListItem(context, itemList[i], i),
          );
          return _listView;
        });
  }

  Stream<QuerySnapshot> _buildStream(User user) {
    return Firestore.instance
        .collection('items')
        .where('testId', isEqualTo: user.ID)
        .snapshots();
  }
```

I still have the real time update on my data list but without the unnecessary calls to Firestore.